# Converting List<ArrayList> to String[]

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop

I have a

```
List<ArrayList> arg = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
```

with

```
[[logo], [cd_branche], [lib_branche]],

(other arguments not relevant) 

[[1111,22222,3333]],[[2222,324,432]]...
```

and I want to cast it to a String[] so I did this

```
    Object[] obj = arg.toArray();
    String[] headers =new String[obj.length];

    for(int i=0;i<headers.length;i++) { 
        headers[i]= (String) obj[i]; 
        }
```

but I'm getting

```
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

The output I'm looking for is

```
headers[0]=logo
headers[1]=cd_branche
headers[2]=lib_branche
```

Using Java 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want it to be an array of strings (i.e. `"[["logo", "cd_branche", "lib_cranche"],[..],[..],[1111,22222,3333],[2222,324,432]"`).

In that case simply do:

```
Object[] obj = arg.toArray();
String[] headers =new String[obj.length];
for(int i=0;i<headers.length;i++) { 
    headers[i]= Arrays.toString(obj);
}
```

And each one of your ArrayList objects inside `obj` will be returned in string array format.

---

**UPDATE:** Since you want it as a flat array, you'll need to (a) compute the size of the array needed and (b) run through your object with two loops and make a deep search as such:

```
int size = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arg.size(); size += arg.get(i++).size());

String[] headers =new String[size];
for(int count = 0, i=0;i<arg.size();i++) {
    for (int j=0; j< arg.get(i).size(); j++) {
        headers[count++]= arg.get(i).get(j).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, what I want is a String[] headers with headers[1]="logo" headers[2]="cd_branch" and so on

Answer (score 0):

String headers = "";
for (String header:arg) 
{headers += header;}